# In IIS how can I force a specific MIME type for all files in a virtual folder?

Tags: iis, mime-types, content-type

I want to force a specific MIME type for all files in a given virtual folder. These are all JPEG files but not all of them have an extension. I've looked for a way to do it in the custom headers or in a web.config but have not found anything. I could set up a MIME type setting for each file type but this doesn't work for the files with no extension.

Any ideas on how to set this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the MIME types configuration for the virtual folder add:
Extension: .*
MIME type: image/jpeg